# How does Java determine if interfaces are inconsistent?

Tags: java, interface, compiler-errors

In particular, what goes on under the hood at compile/run time that will produce an error in the event that interfaces are inconsistent?

Example interfaces:

```
public interface Interface1 {
  int NUM = 0;
}
public interface Interface2 {
  int NUM = 1;
}
```

This has a compiler error:

```
public class Test implements Interface1, Interface2 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(NUM);
 }
}
```

This runs just fine:

```
public class Test implements Interface1, Interface2 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("anything");
 }
}
```

When java encounters `NUM` it finds the definition from the interface. It can't check both at the same time, so why doesn't it just use the definition from `Interface1` (which was implemented first)? Was it designed to check consistency in all the interfaces?

Comment: What do you mean by "it can't check both at the same time"?

Comment: "why doesn't it just use the definition from Interface1" - why should it ? why not use the definition from Interface2? why not invent a new value ? why not throw an exception ? Because, programming languages should be consistent, and the behavior you'd like Java to implement isn't: it will create an unexpected behavior so it's very good that you're getting a compilation error!

Comment: This kind of collision is uncommon, but you can add the possibility to the list of reasons why putting constants in an interface is [considered an antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382728/constant-interface-anti-pattern-clarification).

Comment: This is not a case of 'inconsistent' interfaces. It is a simple name collision.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, what you've got here is the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) - `Interface1` has a field, and `Interface2` has a field.  Both of them are used in their implementing class, but which one "wins" is undefined.  What if `Interface1.NUM` was 100 and `Interface2.NUM` was 1000?  What would the behavior be then?  What if the behavior was inconsistent - sometimes during runs it became 100, and sometimes it was 1000?

It's ambiguous as to which `NUM` was defined "first".  There's no specification around which interface is actually accepted as the "first" one in sequence.  Java doesn't know enough about the implementation to trust one implementation over the other, so it gives up - both of them are too ambiguous to let the runtime make a judgment call.

Comment: This isn't really a diamond pattern, though; there is no common base class.