# How to access a constant from multiple interfaces in java?

Tags: java, interface

I have two interfaces which both use these two constants

```
static final File UPLOAD_DIR = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.home") + File.separator + "uploads");
static final String UPLOAD_DIR_ABSOLUTE_PATH = UPLOAD_DIR.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator;
```

How can I access them without initializing them in both interfaces? Do I create a topmost interface (but these two interfaces do not share any methods)?

Comment: Create a class with Singleton architecture and store vars in that class

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
public interface MyConstants {
    public static final File UPLOAD_DIR = 
        new File(System.getProperty("catalina.home") +
                 File.separator + "uploads");
    public static final String UPLOAD_DIR_ABSOLUTE_PATH = 
        UPLOAD_DIR.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator;
}

public interface InterfaceA extends MyConstants {
    ...
}

public interface InterfaceB extends MyConstants {
    ...
}

public class Test implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
    // Use UPLOAD_DIR
}
```

Note that it is legal Java for a class to inherit an interface's constant declarations via multiple routes.

(It is a matter of personal taste or style whether you used modifiers in interface constant declarations.  According to the JLS, they are **implicitly** `public` `static` `final`; see [JLS 9.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3).)

---

But just because you *can* do something doesn't *necessarily* mean that you should do it.  Some people consider declaring an interface that consists solely of constants to be an Anti-pattern.

Read the following and make up your own mind:

- Wikipedia: [Constant interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface)
- [Why the Constant Interface Pattern Should Be Discouraged](https://dzone.com/articles/reasons-why-the-constant-interface-pattern-is-disc)
- [Constant Interface Anti-Pattern Clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382728)

Comment: You should include that using interfaces to collect constants is rarely considered a good practice. I think many people strongly suggest to not do that at all.

Comment: @Stephen C thank you, I have already used a Singleton class as suggested by Iman, but I will look at this as well (esp. the links)

Comment: No, but an interface can extend another interface.