# Utility class alternative for private static field

Tags: java, oop

```
import java.io.File;

public final class MultiplatformUtility {
    private static final String SEPARATOR = File.separator;

    private MultiplatformUtility() { }

    public static String getSeparator() {
        return SEPARATOR;
    }
}
```

I want SEPARATOR to be in a unique file. Is there a way to avoid using a utility class here but maintain SEPARATOR field static and private?

Edit:
How about a ENUM inside of a Class?

```
import java.io.File;

public class Multiplatform {

    public enum Common {
        SEPARATOR(File.separator);
    
        private final String separator;

        Common(final String separator) {
            this.separator = separator;
        }

        public String getSeparator() {
            return separator;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java forces you to use a class. But:
If your `SEPARATOR` is `final` and `static`, why make it `private`?

Comment: The alternative would be to use an interface but that's actually [considered an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382728/constant-interface-anti-pattern-clarification)

Comment: Why not using File.separator directly?

Comment: I don't wanna repeat File.separator in different files if I have to use it often

Comment: @mitra02 what do you mean by that?  Isn't your alternative repeating `MultiplatformUtility.getSeparator()`?

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, it doesn't make sense to make `SEPARATOR` as `private`, considering also that is a `public` member of `java.io.File`, so you are restricting the access qualifier of an already existing field. That is against the encapsulation and inheritance best practice.

Bear in mind that when you make it `private`, only that class will have access to its value, unless you provide a specific method to get access to it, just as you did with `MultiplatformUtility`. 
As possible solution to your goal, you could have a `public abstract` class in a separated file, and make the field protected, so only the classes which extends your abstract class will have access to it. Personally, this is NOT best practice.

Normally, you define an `interface` and add all constants in it, so it can be used by all classes among your application, but in that case each constant will be by default `public static final`.

Even better, you can define an `enum` in a sepated class, just as in your example, which gives you also more advantages than an interface as you get some utility functions by the fact that implicitly extends `java.lang.Enum`, plus you can define fields, methods and implement interfaces.